# Do resizable UIImages work, when assigning to CALayers' contents property?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiimage, core-graphics

I'd like my `UIImage` to be resized, with respect to `UIEdgeInsets`. Normally resizing occurs, when setting an `UIImageView`'s frame. In my case I don't use a `UIImageView`, but assign the image to the `contents` property of a `CALayer` (its underlying `CGImage` actually).

But guess what, it does not work :(

What do you think is the problem? Maybe using the `CGImage` representation? Or does resizable images only work with UIViews at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resizable images are a UIKit-level feature that CoreAnimation doesn't know about. If you need something other than linear stretching at the CoreAnimation layer, you can use the [`contentsCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW74) or [`contentsGravity`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW20) properties.